# How to pass URL to template filter in Django templates

Tags: django, templates, filter

I have a condition where I am struck and finding a better way to deal with it.
I have a `<li>` in HTML. 
I want to add `class="active"` if certain URL is open.

### Example

if Login page is open that would mean i have `/login/` href in my request.path.

For that i have wrote a template filter, and i am calling it like that.

```
{% if request|is_open:"login" %}
    <li class="active">
        {% else %}
    <li>
{% endif %}
<a href="{% url 'login' %}">Login Here</a>
</li>
```

But i need a much cleaner way to deal with it. 
Can i pass `{%url 'login' %}` to template filter? so that i can pass that named url to the template filter and it lets me know if this is url that has been opened or not.

Right now, the work is really Hard coded, which I want to change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
{% url 'login' as login_url %}
<li {% if request|is_active:login_url %}class="active" {% endif %}
  ...
</li>
<a href="{{ login_url }}">Login here</a>
```

Comment: This is what i was looking for. Thanks.  What is `login_url` scope ?

Comment: The whole current template AFAICT, and at least the current block (if you're in a block).

Answer (score 2):

The `url` takes an optional `as` clause which saves the result in a variable:

```
{% url 'login' as login_url %}
```

which you can then use elsewhere. Note that with this syntax, the value itself is not output from the tag, you'll need to explicitly do so via `{{ login_url }}`.